# How to make my Tkinter/Python GUI render?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to use Tkinter to create a simple log in page in a green, yellow, and white colour set as seen throughout my code but for some reason the code is returning a colourless page and the button is just a rectangle. I don't know what's wrong. No bugs found in the code, can someone please help me?[Bland login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfJ2R.png)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import Style

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Login Page")

def new_page():
    root.title("Page")
    frame.destroy()
    new_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#F0F0F0")
    new_frame.pack(pady=20)

    label = tk.Label(new_frame, text="This is a page that is different ig", bg="#F0F0F0", fg="#000000")
    label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

def verify_login():
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()

    if username.lower() == "admin" and password == "Password1234":
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Login Successful\nWelcome, admin!")
        new_page()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(message="Login Failed\nInvalid username or password")

root.configure(bg="#F0F0F0")

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#F0F0F0")
frame.pack(pady=20)

username_label = tk.Label(frame, text="Username:", fg="#333333", bg="#F0F0F0", font=("Arial", 12))
username_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

username_entry = tk.Entry(frame, fg="#333333", bg="#FFFFFF", highlightthickness=0, font=("Arial", 12))
username_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

password_label = tk.Label(frame, text="Password:", fg="#333333", bg="#F0F0F0", font=("Arial", 12))
password_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

password_entry = tk.Entry(frame, fg="#333333", bg="#FFFFFF", show="*", highlightthickness=0, font=("Arial", 12))
password_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

login_button = tk.Button(frame, text="Login", command=verify_login, bd=0, relief=tk.FLAT)
login_button.configure(bg="#4CAF50", fg="#FFFFFF", font=("Arial", 12))
login_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

style = Style()
style.configure("TButton", relief=tk.FLAT)
style.map("TButton",
          foreground=[('active', '#FFFFFF')],
          background=[('active', '#45A049')])

root.mainloop()
```

I was expecting a green themed page, not what I got though.

Comment: The Login button appears green on my computer. Which version of python and which OS are you using?

Comment: You can't change the background color of standard tkinter buttons on OSX.